# Unable to make a post call using httpconnectionurl and outstreamwriter

Tags: java, json, httpurlconnection

Below is the code i am testing with. When i run this i see that post body is empty. i can see all my header when i trace on the server side but the body is empty. Can you please point out my mistake here ?

````
 String jsonstring = "{\"id\":\"1233\", \"userName\" : \"jump2\"}";
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonstring);
        System.out.println(jsonObject.toJSONString());
        Long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        URL restUrl = new URL("http://myservers.com/v1/register");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) restUrl.openConnection();
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("X-CORRELATION-ID", currentTime.toString());
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("X-AUTH-APIKEY", "dDEdfaeFFDdddDF");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        jsonObject.writeJSONString(outputStreamWriter);
        System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(urlConnection.getRequestMethod());
        System.out.println(urlConnection.getContentEncoding());
        outputStreamWriter.flush();
        outputStreamWriter.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();```
````

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Request method to POST

```
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

[Example for HttpUrlConnection](https://www.baeldung.com/httpurlconnection-post#3-set-the-request-method).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the setting the setDoOutput(true) make this a post request by default ?

Comment: No setting setDoOutputTrue(true) does not make it a POST request. In fact, setDoOutput is defined in URLConnection, it's not even overriden by HttpURLConnection, implying it's independant of the Http protocol. If my answer has fixed your problem, kindly mark it as "accepted" (tick mark).

Comment: unfortunetly it doesn't work. However when i replace 

```
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        jsonObject.writeJSONString(outputStreamWriter);````


 ```OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        out.write(jsonstring.getBytes());```

it works as expected.